# How to I pass a String and Object using Custom Annotations in Java

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a way to pass values through the @LogMethod annotation. I want to pass a String and an Object (DataFileVO). How Can I do it?

Something like this.

```
@LogMethod(logLevel = LoggerOne.DEBUG, duaNum = "23L", duaDataFile = myListObject)
```

**LoggerOne.java**

```
public enum LoggerOne {
    INFO, DEBUG;
}
```

**LogMethod.java**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogMethod {
   LoggerOne logLevel() default LoggerOne.INFO;
 }
```

**Util.java**

```
public class Util {

public static void log(Object o, String methodName) {
    Class klass = o.getClass();

    for (Method m : klass.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            for (Annotation a : m.getAnnotations()) {
                if (a instanceof LogMethod) {
                    LogMethod lm = (LogMethod) a;
                    switch (lm.logLevel()) {
                      case INFO:
                        System.out.println("Performing Custom INFO logging for " + m.getName());
                        break;
                      case DEBUG:
                        System.out.println("Performing Custom DEBUG logging for " + m.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

**DataFileDaoImpl.java**

```
    @LogMethod(logLevel = LoggerOne.DEBUG)
public List<DuaDataFileVO> getDuaByDuaAndShipperCode(String duaNum, Long shipperCode) {
     List<DuaDataFileVO> list = new ArrayList<DuaDataFileVO>();
     // Some code
        return list;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you like to reach. Something like this would be possible: @LogMethod(logLevel = LoggerOne.DEBUG, message = "Debug Prefix:"). But attaching any dynamic data to an annotation or something like this is obviously not possible (the annotation is attachted to a method, not to a specific call ...).

Comment: So, I cannot do something like this?
@LogMethod(logLevel = LoggerOne.DEBUG, duaNum = "23", duaDataFile = "somelistObject")

Comment: Sure. You can provide any static data you like to the annotation. Just add methods like "int duaNum();" to the annotation declaration and your code can then do whatever it wants with that data.

Comment: and what about an entire Object?

Comment: No, only primitives, Strings, Class objects ... no other instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotations are only 'metadata' and not part of the concrete program.
So, if you're compile a program, the metadata will not exist any more.

Read [Lesson: Annotations - ORACLE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) for more informations.

I think you can solve your problem with 'Aspect-oriented programming'.
Here is a Tutorial [Java Method Logging with AOP and Annotations](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html).

**The following code comes from this tutorial.**

*The important code is the aspect:*

```
@Aspect
public class MethodLogger {
  @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Loggable)")
  public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object result = point.proceed();
    Logger.info(
      "#%s(%s): %s in %[msec]s",
      MethodSignature.class.cast(point.getSignature()).getMethod().getName(),
      point.getArgs(),
      result,
      System.currentTimeMillis() - start
    );
    return result;
  }
}
```

This aspect is working around an execution (method) - which has any modifier, any name and any arguments - that is annotated with @Loggable.
The MethodLogger prints a 'Info' with the classpath, method-name, arguments, the result and the execution-time from the executed method.

*You can use this annotation like this:*

```
public class Foo {
  @Loggable
  public int power(int x, int p) {
    return Math.pow(x, p);
  }
}
```

*With this example-output:*

```
[INFO] com.example.Foo #power(2, 10): 1024 in 12μs
```

*You need this dependencies to compile:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jcabi</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcabi-aspects</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The tutorial is very hepful.
To unsterstand why it works, read it completely.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: For compiling single aspects, you can read [stackoverflow-article](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1009838/4508372).